# android 2.3 set preferenceActivity background but flushing when scrolling

Tags: android, android-preferences

I meet a Ui problem,I use a preferenceActivity to finish my software's settings function.But I set a image to the preferenceActivity's listview background or preferenceActivity's background,then I scroll the listview,the background image will be flushed or gone,can anyone meet this problem before?I test it on android 4.0,this issue doesn't exist.

Comment: This was a really tricky one for me to diagnose, and took several Stack Overflow searches to find this answer. It's also going to be a very common problem. It'd be nice to clean up the question a bit so that it's easier to find. (I'll work on it myself if you like.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely an issue with the `cacheColorHint` property of the `ListView`, which is designed to aid scrolling performance when lists have a solid background.  It can be removed by setting the `cacheColorHint` to be transparent.

You can read this Android Developers blog post for more information:

[Why is my list black?](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)

Comment: I have set that property to transparent,the issue still exists in preference activity.

Comment: success,I forget to use getResource to load color by color id.